# How do I apply a texture to a quad in GTK or Cairo?

Tags: c, image, gtk3

I am trying to make an image to fit a quadrilateral.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    GtkWidget (*Image) = gtk_image_new_from_file("image.png");
    GtkWidget (*Window) = gtk_window_new(0);
    gtk_image_set_pixel_size(GTK_IMAGE(Image), 200);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(Window), Image);
    gtk_widget_show_all(Window);
    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

Suppose I have 8 variables. Each corresponding to the vertices of a quadrilateral. `x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3 x4 y4` These eight numbers correspond to four points on the window/drawing area that can be used to construct a quadrilateral. These numbers are representing points that are `x` pixels from the left and `y` from the top of the window, and since there are 4, the numbers represent which one. I have been trying to figure this out for a long time. How can I use those to create a quadrilateral, and stretch  the image to fit inside? Also, I want to avoid including header files other than the standard ones and gtk if possible. Basically I need to load an image from a file which is square and then transform it to match the desired shape. How exactly do I do that? Don't think I am trying to edit image files, I am actually trying to render block faces for a block sandbox game.

I do appreciate the help, but I still don't quite know how to do what I am describing. Something I need to know is should I use a `GtkDrawingArea` or not?

[I think I found something for the Mac version of what I am looking for](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/creating_and_sampling_textures), but how can I do this in GTK?

For more information, I am trying to render textures in the form of a 3D game.

In Metal tutorials, this is one of the first features taught. Is this possible in GTK/Cairo, or do I need to scrap my progress and use OpenGL or something for Linux.

Comment: Are there any contraints on the shape of your quadrilateral? Are you talking about scaling, rotating or distorting the image or any combination of them?

Comment: @Gerhardh If you think about it, there is no need for scaling or rotating. The `x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3 x4 y4` will be able to construct any quadrilateral. These correspond to the vertices, I don't have any constraints, and all I need to to is use these find out how to make a quadrilateral, then position the vertices using these eight numbers, and then place an image inside, and stretch it to fit

Comment: I understand that your coordinates are enough to define any shape. My assumption is that the image you load from the file is rectangular and you need to transform it to match your desired shape.

Comment: Easy to do in ImageMagick. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#perspective

Comment: @Gerhardh Yes your assumption is correct. So how exactly do I do that?

Comment: @fmw42 I took a look at that, but I do not see how to do that in C using GTK3

Comment: Unfortunately, I only know the command line. So I cannot help further. See https://imagemagick.org/api/magick-image.php for C API methods.

Comment: Without any constraints I have no idea. You might follow those ImageMagick links.

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is an arbitrary linear transformation. Since Gtk is built on top of cairo graphics you would be well suited to look therein (https://www.cairographics.org/manual/cairo-Transformations.html). All linear transformations can be represented by a transformation matrix, which cairo uses as part of its drawing model. It does however say that it is an affine matrix which means that parallel lines are preserved (i.e. not all linear transformations can be represented and your quadrilateral will have to also be a parallelogram).

The use of affine matrices is common for many graphical backends. If you want to get around it for arbitrary distortions (e.g. perspective) the use of ImageMagick (has FFMPEG as a backend) would be a good approach. OpenGL will also have these capabilities (being 3D you need this for doing orthographic projections eg.)

In order to get the transformation matrix you will need to solve a set of simultaneous equations. Software that would help with this includes libBLAS, Eigen and OpenCV.

Comment: Do I need to do this: `#include <cairo.h>` orr not?

Comment: If you are choosing to use cairo, absolutely. Make sure you have the development headers installed and a path to them at compile time.

Comment: Do I have to use cairo, or is it possible to only use gtk3

Comment: How exactly do I make a transformation matrix using the eight numbers?

Comment: Gtk by default uses cairo. Gtk3 can also use wayland as a backend, which is built on OpenGL

Comment: so you are saying cairo is part of gtk like pango?

Comment: The transformation matrix multiplies position vectors to become new position vectors. Each coordinate transformed gives an equation for each matrix row. You then build up the simultaneous equations for each coordinate, put it in matrix form and then invert to solve for the unknowns. A linear algebra library allows you to do this most efficiently.

Comment: I don't quite understand that

Comment: Also would I add cairo shapes to a drawing area? What place do I add cairo shapes to?

Comment: Yes. The drawing area is used for cairo operations. Check out some of their tutorials.

Comment: you mean the `GtkDrawingArea` that is initialized by the initializer `gtk_drawing_area_new()`?

Comment: Seriously check out the tutorials then come back with new questions. SO comments aren't meant for extended discussions.

Comment: Tutorials? Literally NO WHERE does developer.gnome.org say how to do this. I am not even sure GTK3 supports this feature